# c# If statement to include another form to perform an action

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a button on a completion form, which when pressed opens up a windows explorer.

This was ok, when i only had 1 directory.
I now have 2 directories, which are now set from my main form.

What i would like to do, is when the button is pressed, if a combobox on my main form is for example "Apples" then opens up a coded directory.
If the combobox on my main for is "Pears" then open up a different directory.

I have the following code to open up the original directory - just dont know how to include the second, as i cant seem to access the combobox from the completion form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        this.Hide();
        FrmMain form3 = new FrmMain();
        form3.Show();
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    {               
        FileName = "C:\\Directory 1\\",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "open"
    });
}
```

Hope you can help.

Thanks - Craig.

Comment: did u try FileName = "C:\\" + combobox.SelectedValue ?

Comment: why do you have `{ }` wrapped around your first 3 lines of code..? remove them

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your mainform class is called `MainForm` and that the combobox instance inside it is called `directoryComboBox`.

Now, the first step consists in creating a property in your `MainForm` that exposes the currently selected value of the `directoryComboBox` instance:

```
public String CurrentDirectory
{
    get { return directoryComboBox.Text; }
}
```

In your `CompletionForm` class, add the following field (used as a reference to the parent `MainForm` instance):

```
private MainForm m_Parent;
```

and modify the constructor as follows:

```
public CompletionForm(MainForm parent)
{
    m_Parent = parent;
}
```

Finally, modify the code of your `MainForm` in which you create a new completion form and show it to the user as follows:

```
CompletionForm cf = new CompletionForm(this); // this is the current instance of `MainForm` showing the completion form
cf.ShowDialog(this);
```

In your `CompletionForm` you can now have access to the currently selected value of your `directoryComboBox`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        {               
            FileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\", m_Parent.CurrentDirectory),
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "open"
        });
```

You could also construct your `CompletionForm` instance by directly passing it the current `directoryComboBox` value. The approach is very similar and it doesn't require you to modify your `MainForm` class adding a new property. All you have to do is to edit the right `CompletionForm` portions of code:

```
private String m_CurrentDirectory;

public CompletionForm(String currentDirectory)
{
    m_CurrentDirectory = currentDirectory;
}

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        {               
            FileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\", m_CurrentDirectory),
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "open"
        });
```

and the `MainForm` method that instantiates it:

```
CompletionForm cf = new CompletionForm(directoryComboBox.Text);
cf.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: This is correct, i am unable to access a combobox from another form to be included in my if statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you could do this. I'm supposing your completion form is opened from the main form. The cleanest way would be to inject the current selection of the main form's combobox upon creation. Something in the line of:

```
 var completionForm = new CompletionForm(directoryCombo.Text);
 completionForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Do note that `ShowDialog` is relevant. This ensures that no one will change the selected directory while the completion form is active. If this not the case, and the completion form isn't modal, then a better alternative is to implement a public property in your main form:

```
public string SelectedDirectory => directoryCombo.Text;
```

And then simply access it form your completion form:

```
var selectedDirectory = (Owner as mainForm).SelectedDirectory;
```